# logical problem in Trie insertion or a read operation

Tags: string, algorithm, data-structures, information-retrieval, trie

I am trying the insertion operation in a Trie and a read operation for the below implementation I am having trouble with insertion.  I don't think there's is any problem with the reading operation.  In my case, each node of Trie has an array of node pointers and a value field. Also, I am marking each character insertion theoretically each node has uppercase char and an integer value. For example: say 3 strings are to be added given as **ATAGA**, **ATC**, and **GAT**  so each of the characters has a value which will be given by the "**pass**" variable in the code, see expected output for more details.

```
import java.util.*;

class node{
  public int val;
  public node ptrs[];
  node(){
      this.val =0;
      ptrs = new node[26];
      for (node ptr : ptrs) {
          ptr = null;
      }
    }    
}

class Tree{
  public node root = new node();
  public int pass =0;
  void insert(String s) {
      node trv = root;
      for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
          if (trv.ptrs[s.charAt(i) - 'A'] == null) {
              trv.ptrs[s.charAt(i) - 'A'] = new node();
              trv.val = ++pass;
            //  System.out.println(s.charAt(i)+" val : "+trv.val);
          } 
          trv = trv.ptrs[s.charAt(i) - 'A'];
      }
  }

  private void visit(node trv){
      for(int i =0;i<26;i++){
          if(trv.ptrs[i]!=null){
              System.out.println((char)(i+'A')+" : "+trv.val);
              visit(trv.ptrs[i]);
          }
      }
  }
  void call(){
      this.visit(root);
   }
}

public class trie {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    Tree t = new Tree();
    while (n-- > 0) {
        String s = sc.next();
        t.insert(s);
    }
    t.call();
    sc.close();
 }
}
```

my output :

```
3
ATAGA
ATC
GAT
A : 7
T : 2
A : 6
G : 4
A : 5
C : 6
G : 7
A : 8
T : 9
```

expected output :

```
3
ATAGA
ATC
GAT
A : 1
T : 2
A : 3
G : 4
A : 5
C : 6
G : 7
A : 8
T : 9
```

Comment: Also as a side note, would you mind suggesting any optimizations here, Things I am not able to see. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tested the changes and I can see the expected output as you mentioned.

You have to update the children nodes val and ptrs array not the parent during the insertion.

```
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) 
{
          if (trv.ptrs[s.charAt(i) - 'A'] == null) 
          {
              trv.ptrs[s.charAt(i) - 'A'] = new node();
              trv.ptrs[s.charAt(i) - 'A'].val = ++pass;
          }
}
```

Similarly during the search/visit, fetch the value from the child node of the current node.

```
for(int i=0;i<26;i++)
{
          if(trv.ptrs[i]!=null)
          {
              System.out.println((char)(i+'A')+" : "+trv.ptrs[i].val);
              visit(trv.ptrs[i]);
          }
}
```

Comment: Amazing one, mate such a subtle mistake it took me a whole day until now, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

In these lines:

```
trv.val = ++pass;
System.out.println((char)(i+'A')+" : "+trv.val);
```

you should be using `trv.ptrs[s.charAt(i) - 'A'].val` instead of `trv.val`

i.e. you want to get/set the value of the child node, and not the parent.

Comment: Refer to this link for problem statement [link](https://github.com/pawan-nirpal-031/AlgorithmsLab/blob/master/_f8a4443f144319c6da63eeb31af4199b_Programming-Assignment-1.pdf), first problem in this pdf.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `trv.ptrs[s.charAt(i) - 'A'].val`. See my edit

Comment: Thank you @nullptr. I appreciate the time you took to look into my problem.